# Completion and metrics of normed vector spaces

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

$\newcommand{\vertiii}[1]{{\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert #1 
    \right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert}}$

Let $(V, \|\cdot \|_0)$ and $(W, \|\cdot \|_1)$ be normed vector spaces.

Given that $(\overline{V},\overline{d}_0)$ is a completion of $(V,d_0)$ (where $d_0(v,x)=\|v-x\|_0$), and $(\overline{W},\overline{d}_1)$ is a completion of $(W,d_1)$ (with $d_1(y,w)=\|y-w\|_1$), then $(\overline{V}\times \overline{W},\overline{d})$ is a completion of $(V\times W, d)$ with $\overline{d}((\overline{x}, \overline{y}),(\overline{v}, \overline{w}))=\overline{d}_0(\overline{x}, \overline{v})+\overline{d}_1(\overline{y}, \overline{w})$, where $d((x,y),(v,w))=\vertiii{(x,y)-(v,w)}=\|x-v\|_0+\|y-w\|_1$.

As far as I understand, the argument should be based on the fact that, since $(\overline{V}, \overline{d}_0)$ is a completion of $(V,d)$, there is an isometry $\overline{\iota}:V\to \overline{V}$ such that $\overline{\overline{\iota}(V)}=\overline{V}$ and $d_0(\overline{\iota}(x),\overline{\iota}(v))=d_0(x,v)$. Similarly, there is an isometry $\overline{\phi}:W\to \overline{W}$.

Now, I'm not quite sure what to do next, since I'm not convinced that I fully understand how these isometries work, so just want to make sure I'm doing it right. Here's how my proof goes next:

> Thus $(\overline{\overline{\iota}(V)}\times \overline{\overline{\phi}(W)})=\overline{V}\times \overline{W}$ with $\overline{d_0}(\overline{\iota}(x),\overline{\iota}(v))=
> \overline{d_0(x,v)}=\overline{d}_0(\overline{x},\overline{v})$ and  $\overline{d_1(\overline{\phi}(y),\overline{\phi}(w))}=
> \overline{d_1(y,w)}=\overline{d}_1(\overline{y},\overline{w})$. Thus $\overline{d}((\overline{x},\overline{v}),(\overline{y},\overline{w}))=\overline{d}_0(\overline{v},\overline{x})+\overline{d}_1(\overline{w},\overline{y})$.

Please let me know if I'm not missing something in my argument.

Also, what is the difference between a completion of a metric space and its closure? Is it that $\mathbb{R}$ is a closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, but it is also a completion of $\mathbb{R}$, while $\mathbb{C}$ is a completion but not a closure of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @reuns Can you please let me know if my proof is correct?

Comment: A proof of what ? If $k(x,y)$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $\|.\|_{V \times W} = k(\|.\|_V,\|.\|_W)$ is a norm on $V \times  W$. All norms are equivalent on $\mathbb{R}^2$ thus all such norms are equivalent on $V \times  W$. When $V,W$ are Hilbert spaces of course the preferred choice is $k(x,y) = \sqrt{a^2 x^2+b^2 y^2}$ so that $V \times W$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: The completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ but seen as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. In functional analysis we are talking of real or complex vector spaces. And $\mathbb{C}$ is a field extension or a $2$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space which is a different thing (it is also the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$).  $\ell^2$ is the completion of the real or complex vector space of finite length sequences with the norm $\|x\| = (\sum_n |x_n|^2)^{1/2}$. Closure can mean making a set closed for a topology.

Comment: @reuns I mean do you think that my line of reasoning with isometries is correct?
Also, $\mathbb{R}$ is both a completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ and its closure, correct?

Comment: You are making trivial things complicated ($V$ embeds in $\overline{V}$ by definition). What is not correct is assuming $\overline{d}((\overline{x},\overline{v}),(\overline{y},\overline{w}))=\overline{d}_0(\overline{v},\overline{x})+\overline{d}_1(\overline{w},\overline{y})$ whereas $.+.$ can be replaced by any function $k(.,.)$ I mentioned. Completion and closure **for what** (norm, metric, topology, operation) ? I'd say complete and completion is for a norm or metric, "closed under" or closure is for anything else. $\mathbb{R}$ is a field because the norm on $\mathbb{Q}$ is an absolute value

Comment: The completion of a metric space is defined intrinsically by the topology of the space itself. The closure of a subset $S$ of a topological space is defined with respect to the topology of the containing space, thus it is NOT intrinsically defined by $S$, even if it is regarded as a topological space by itself. For example, the completion of the interval $[0, 1)$ with the distance induced by the modulus "is", upon an identification, the closed interval $[0, 1]$. The closure of the same interval in the topological space $[-1, 1)$ with the topology induced by the modulus is $[0, 1)$.